# Insert Clear Fix After Certain Amount of DIVs in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling with a problem and I thought someone could help me. I'm trying to insert a clear div after a certain amount div containers. Now in this example I've managed to get it to work that after the first three a clear div is placed, but I want it to be inserted after each set of 3 divs depending on how many featured articles I've setup (3, 6, 9 etc).

```
$featured_articles = get_field('featured_articles', false, false );
    $id = $featured_articles[0];
    //var_dump();
    $numberOfArticles = count($featured_articles);
    //var_dump($featured_articles);
    echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";

            for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfArticles; $i++) { 
                if ($featured_articles) {
                        $id = $featured_articles[$i];

                        //var_dump($featured_articles);
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail($id) ) {

                            echo "<div class='span4'>";
                            echo "<article class='post__holder recipes'>";
                            echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."' class='image'>";
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'medium-thumb' );
                                $image_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'large');
                            echo "</a>";
                        }
                        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."'><h3>".get_the_title($id)."</h3></a>";
                        echo "<div class='starRating'>";
                        echo "<img src='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/BUZZBLOG-theme/images/StarRating.svg' alt='Testergebnis'>";
                        echo "<div class='bar' style='width:".get_field('rating', $id)."%'></div>";
                        echo "</div>";/** end starrating **/
                        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."'><div class='readmore-button'>Zum Testbericht...</div></a>";
                        echo "</div>"; 
                        echo "</article>";
                        if ($i >= 2) {
                            if($i == 2) { 
                                echo "<div class='clearfix'>";
                            }
                            if ($i == $numberOfArticles) {
                                echo "</div>";
                            }
                        }


                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Can you show what kind of data you are getting in `$featured_articles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this It will check for multiples of 3 and place a clearfix div

Also dont forget to start the $i from 1 upto $i <= $numberOfArticles

```
$featured_articles = get_field('featured_articles', false, false );
    $id = $featured_articles[0];
    //var_dump();
    $numberOfArticles = count($featured_articles);
    //var_dump($featured_articles);
    echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<div class='row-fluid'>";

            for ($i=1; $i <= $numberOfArticles; $i++) { 
                if ($featured_articles) {
                        $id = $featured_articles[$i-1];

                        //var_dump($featured_articles);
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail($id) ) {

                            echo "<div class='span4'>";
                            echo "<article class='post__holder recipes'>";
                            echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."' class='image'>";
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'medium-thumb' );
                                $image_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'large');
                            echo "</a>";
                        }
                        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."'><h3>".get_the_title($id)."</h3></a>";
                        echo "<div class='starRating'>";
                        echo "<img src='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/BUZZBLOG-theme/images/StarRating.svg' alt='Testergebnis'>";
                        echo "<div class='bar' style='width:".get_field('rating', $id)."%'></div>";
                        echo "</div>";/** end starrating **/
                        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($id)."'><div class='readmore-button'>Zum Testbericht...</div></a>";
                        echo "</div>"; 
                        echo "</article>";
                       if($i%3==0) {
                                echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
                            }



                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:-

```
for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfArticles; $i++) { 
  // your code
  if($i%3==0) echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk()` function to divide your array in group of 3 members each and you can iterate over each array.

> PHP is a server side scripting language that is embedded in HTML.

So use this feature in your code instead of writing `echo "html element"` every where in code.

I think you have miss match of `div` element. Because `<article>`  must be close before the `<div class='span4'>` but in your code it is not there.

```
$featured_articles = get_field('featured_articles', false, false );
    $dividedIn3GroupsEach = array_chunk($featured_articles, 3);    
    foreach ($dividedIn3GroupsEach as $array) {
        ?>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row-fluid'>
                <?php
                foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                    $id = $featured_articles[$key];
                    if (has_post_thumbnail($id)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class='span4'>
                            <article class='post__holder recipes'>
                                <a href='<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>' class='image'>
                                    <?php
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'medium-thumb');
                                    $image_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'large');
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <a href='<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>'><h3><?php echo get_the_title($id); ?></h3></a>
                            <div class='starRating'>
                                <img src='<?php echo home_url() ?>"/wp-content/themes/BUZZBLOG-theme/images/StarRating.svg' alt='Testergebnis'>
                                <div class='bar' style='width:<?php echo get_field('rating', $id); ?>%'></div>
                            </div>
                            <a href='<?php echo get_permalink($id); ?>'><div class='readmore-button'>Zum Testbericht...</div></a>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <?php }
                ?>
</div> <!-- row-fluid end -->
</div> <!-- container end -->
                <div class='clearfix'></div>
            <?php } ?>
```

I hope this may help you.